# Curve fitting for n detected peaks and different intensity

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am working on spectroscopy data and I am trying to fit a Gaussian curve for each detected peak(shown as a red dot in the graph) but as shown in the graph, the curves are not as expected and I am not sure what's going wrong in the code can anyone help me to fix this. is there any method that can fit the Gaussian curve?

I am trying to do this - expected curves to calculate the area under curve:

[image: expected curves to calculate the area under curve].

```py
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    return amp * np.exp(-np.power(x - cen,2.) / (2 * np.power(wid,2.)))

for peak_index in above_noise_peaks:
    #filtered data consists of x and y values
    # filtered_intensity is values of y after buterworth filter

    peak_wavenumber = above_noise_x[peak_index]
    peak_intensity = above_noise_data[peak_index]
    peak_height = filtered_intensity[peak_index] - baseline_corrected_intensity[np.argmax(filtered_data[:, 1] >= peak_wavenumber)]

    peak_heights.append(peak_height)

initial_amplitude = peak_intensity
initial_center = peak_wavenumber
initial_width =  10
popt, _ = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian, filtered_data[:, 1], filtered_intensity, p0=[initial_amplitude, initial_center, initial_width])
fitted_curve = gaussian(filtered_data[:, 1], *popt)
plt.plot(filtered_data[:, 1], fitted_curve, label=f'Gaussian Fit - {intensity_column}', color='orange')
```

[image: I am getting this]

for

```py
initial_amplitude = peak_intensity
initial_center = peak_wavenumber
initial_width =  peak_intensity
```

I am getting this:

[image: I am getting this]

Comment: Your low pass filter is **far** too aggressive. You have the domain knowledge of the substance being analysed. What is the huge narrow spike ~610 & ~ 670 ? Alcohol, vinyl or halo-alkane??? It makes sense to find the peaks by using a low pass filtered dataset, but to determine the peak heights and widths you should always fit your model against the original raw data (with baseline correction if needed).

Comment: Can you fix the indentation mistakes / formatting mistakes? For example, I'm guessing that `[I am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxPwF.png)` is not part of your code.

Comment: The way that you are determining the noise floor looks wrong to me. A quick and dirty experimentalists heuristic is that highest to lowest noise peaks on an otherwise flat baseline (or in this case sloping baseline) represents about 6 sigma. Your standard deviation noise level is at most 1/2 of what is marked on the graph in blue (lower in some regions) and the two narrow features near WN 600 are well above the noise floor and incredibly sharp. Most of your peaks also don't look remotely gaussian which will also be a problem for any peak fitting routing.

Comment: Hello martin,
# Calculate running noise with a dynamic window
    window_percentage = 55  # Adjust as needed
    running_noise = np.zeros_like(filtered_intensity)
    for i in range(len(filtered_intensity)):
        window_start = max(0, i - int(window_percentage / 100 * len(filtered_intensity)))
        window_end = min(len(filtered_intensity), i + int(window_percentage / 100 * len(filtered_intensity)))
        window_difference = filtered_intensity[window_start:window_end] - baseline_corrected_intensity[window_start:window_end]
        running_noise[i] = np.std(window_difference)

Comment: I have detected peaks above that calculated running noise.. is that causing the problem?

Comment: Try using a Butterworth filter that has a higher frequency passband and that ought to make the other narrow peaks significant over the noise. The noise floor as determined by your code looks to be pessimistic to my experimentalist's rule of thumb. BTW tag replies @username and then I get notified.